# TCP socket.send blocking in C# - what is the specific reason behind the block?

Tags: .net, tcp, blocking

When have two sockets connected to each other (in my test on localhost), I was wondering what would happen if the sender kept sending but the client was too slow to read to keep of with the sending pace.

I did a test where I connect two sockets and start sending without reading at all. The sending starts blocking around 2.7-2.8mb.

When I start receiving some data, the send-call will then unblock and allow for the same amount of data to be sent again before a new block will happen.

The SendingBuffer and ReceivingBuffer are both 65k, so I conclude that these buffers are just internal max storage before flushes will be forced under the hood to the network interface.

Can anyone tell me, where the ~2.7mb limit is defined? Is it the network interface's own output buffer? Is it a window size defined at tcp level that triggers backpreasure? Is it something else?

I have done the test in both dotnet framework and dotnet 5.

Program.cs to reproduce:

```
public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var log = new BlockingCollection<string>();
            var tcpListener = new TcpListener(localaddr: System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, port: 9988);
            tcpListener.Start();
            using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                var connectTask = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host: "127.0.0.1", port: 9988);
                var acceptTask = tcpListener.AcceptSocketAsync();

                Task.WaitAll(connectTask, acceptTask);
                Console.WriteLine("Connection success!");

                var remoteClient = acceptTask.Result;
                remoteClient.NoDelay = true;

                // Write as fast as possible
                var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
                    int byteCountSent = 0;
                    var bytes = new byte[100_000];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        remoteClient.Send(bytes);
                        byteCountSent += bytes.Length;
                        log.Add("Total bytes sent: " + byteCountSent);
                    }
                }));
                t.Start();

                // Read slowly
                var t_receive = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    var bytes = new byte[100_000_000];
                    using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            // Every 10 seconds, read a big chunk to show that sending is then allowed again
                            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                            int bytesReceived = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                            log.Add("Received bytes: " + bytesReceived + ", available: " + tcpClient.Available);

                        }
                    }
                }));

                t_receive.Start();
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + log.Take());
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: My googling so far has led me in the direction to a full kernel buffer. If it is on the sender side this makes sense as a standalone explanation. If the limit is on the receiver side, this full buffer explanation should be combined with a caused TCP backpreasure - and then it would also explain it.

I will look into reading output and input buffers in the OS (Im a windows).

Comment: I tried adding a haproxy docker container between my 2 local listener and client. This increased the amount of available sending data to 20mb+ before stalling.